# Search of Dictionary Keys python

Tags: python, dictionary, search, indexing, associative-array

I want to know how I could perform some kind of index on keys from a python dictionary. The dictionary holds approx. 400,000 items, so I am trying to avoid a linear search.

Basically, I am trying to find if the `userinput` is inside any of the dict keys.

```
for keys in dict:
    if userinput in keys:
        DoSomething()
        break
```

That would be an example of what I am trying to do. Is there a way to search in a more direct way, without a loop ? or what would be a more efficient way.

*Clarification:* The `userinput` is not exactly what the key will be, eg `userinput` could be `log`, whereas the key is `logfile`

*Edit:* any list/cache creation, pre-processing or organisation that can be done prior to searching is acceptable. The only thing that needs to be quick is the search for the key.

Comment: What is the type of your key?  I don't think you need two loops.

Comment: When all available (and implementable) algorithms have inacceptable complexity, it's time to rethink the problem or the data structure used. There are (relatively exotic) data structures for fuzzy string matching, although I don't know if there are any for abritary substrings.

Comment: If userinput will always start at the beginning of a key, then you could create a `keycache` of nested dicts `{'a':{'b':['abacus', 'absinthe'...] ...} ...}`

Comment: The key is just a string, eg 'logfile'

Comment: @Trent: Then your `if userinput in keys` line is wrong.  Can you try removing the for loop, make it work for one item, then update your question with the code you mean?

Comment: But is the userinput always at the beginning of the key?

Comment: @Mikel how is it wrong? Using plural 'keys' is confusing, but `'foo' in 'foobar' is True`. Seems right to me.

Comment: @Trent, @kojiro: Sorry, you're right, I should have tested first.  Yay for Python's string/list duality.

Comment: @Trent, I'm still wondering whether `userinput` is always a _prefix_, as in your 'log'/'logfile' example, or whether `userinput` is an arbitrary substring, as in 'file'/'longfilename'. It makes a pretty big difference.

Comment: substring :) need the flexibility

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to find keys that start with a prefix then you can use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). More complex data structures exist for finding keys that contain a substring anywhere within them, but they take up a lot more space to store so it's a space-time trade-off.

Comment: Ah, "trie" -- guess that's the word I wanted for my comment above. +1

Comment: Wouldn't building the trie itself be quite costly? You'd still have to iterate through the whole dictionary, and at that point, it's not going to be substantially better than the naive solution, and might be worse for the average case.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi, it would be costly initially, but you'd only have to do it once, right? All future prefix lookups would be fast, because you'd look in the trie for a match or matches. (Presumably you'd present a list of potential matches if there are more than one in the trie, or have some other algorithm for picking one.) Furthermore, the trie could be built in advance and pickled; and if the dict changes, it could be updated fairly easily & pickled again at program exit.

Comment: @senderle: Never mind, I posted that before I saw the updated post by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>No. The only way of searching for a string in dictionary keys is to look in each key. Something like what you've suggested is the only way of doing it with a dictionary.</strike>

However, if you have 400,000 records and you want to speed up your search, I'd suggest using an SQLite database. Then you can just say `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%userinput%';`. Look at the documentation for Python's sqlite3 module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Another option is to use a generator expression, as these are almost always faster than the equivalent for loops.

```
filteredKeys = (key for key in myDict.keys() if userInput in key)
for key in filteredKeys:
    doSomething()
```

**EDIT:** If, as you say, you don't care about one-time costs, use a database. SQLite should do what you want damn near perfectly.

I did some benchmarks, and to my surprise, the naive algorithm is actually twice as fast as a version using list comprehensions and *six* times as fast as a SQLite-driven version. In light of these results, I'd have to go with @Mark Byers and recommend a Trie. I've posted the benchmark below, in case someone wants to give it a go.

```
import random, string, os
import time
import sqlite3

def buildDict(numElements):
    aDict = {}
    for i in xrange(numElements-10):
        aDict[''.join(random.sample(string.letters, 6))] = 0

    for i in xrange(10):
        aDict['log'+''.join(random.sample(string.letters, 3))] = 0

    return aDict

def naiveLCSearch(aDict, searchString):
    filteredKeys = [key for key in aDict.keys() if searchString in key]
    return filteredKeys

def naiveSearch(aDict, searchString):
    filteredKeys = []
    for key in aDict:
        if searchString in key: 
            filteredKeys.append(key)
    return filteredKeys

def insertIntoDB(aDict):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/dictdb')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BLAH')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE BLAH (KEY TEXT PRIMARY KEY, VALUE TEXT)')
    for key in aDict:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO BLAH VALUES(?,?)',(key, aDict[key]))
    return conn

def dbSearch(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT KEY FROM BLAH WHERE KEY GLOB '*log*'")
    return [record[0] for record in cursor]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aDict = buildDict(400000)
    conn = insertIntoDB(aDict)
    startTimeNaive = time.time()
    for i in xrange(3):
        naiveResults = naiveSearch(aDict, 'log')
    endTimeNaive = time.time()
    print 'Time taken for 3 iterations of naive search was', (endTimeNaive-startTimeNaive), 'and the average time per run was', (endTimeNaive-startTimeNaive)/3.0

    startTimeNaiveLC = time.time()
    for i in xrange(3):
        naiveLCResults = naiveLCSearch(aDict, 'log')
    endTimeNaiveLC = time.time()
    print 'Time taken for 3 iterations of naive search with list comprehensions was', (endTimeNaiveLC-startTimeNaiveLC), 'and the average time per run was', (endTimeNaiveLC-startTimeNaiveLC)/3.0

    startTimeDB = time.time()
    for i in xrange(3):
        dbResults = dbSearch(conn)
    endTimeDB = time.time()
    print 'Time taken for 3 iterations of DB search was', (endTimeDB-startTimeDB), 'and the average time per run was', (endTimeDB-startTimeDB)/3.0


    os.remove('/tmp/dictdb')
```

For the record, my results were:

```
Time taken for 3 iterations of naive search was 0.264658927917 and the average time per run was 0.0882196426392
Time taken for 3 iterations of naive search with list comprehensions was 0.403481960297 and the average time per run was 0.134493986766
Time taken for 3 iterations of DB search was 1.19464492798 and the average time per run was 0.398214975993
```

All times are in seconds.

Comment: I would shorten the above to "However, if you have 400,000 records, use a database."

Comment: "Another option is to use list comprehensions, as these are almost always faster than the equivalent loops."  Source?

Comment: @Mikel, I don't know a source, but I believe Chinmay is right, simply based on experience.

Comment: @Mikel: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips . Look in the section on Loops.

Comment: @Chinmay But we don't know if he needs to process the entire set of keys. Doing that list comprehension is likely to be costly unless userInput is not actually in the keys at all. I suggest using a generator instead of a list comprehension. Then you can break out after the first match is found.

Comment: @kojiro: Good point, edited my answer. Worst-case will still be the same, since there is no guarantee about the order of the keys, but should be much better in the average and best cases.

Comment: @Chinmay: remove the `.keys()`

Comment: @John: I prefer to leave it in there, as I find it makes the code more obvious as to its intent. I realise that it's not necessary though.

Comment: @Chinmay, sadly (from a readability standpoint) I think John is right; `in mydict.keys()` searches a list, not a dict, and is terribly slow. (Not that it matters now!)

Comment: Flummoxing that the list comprehension is slower... did you try it with a generator?

Comment: Oh! You're creating a `.keys()` list there too. I tested this with `filteredKeys = [key for key in aDict if searchString in key]` and it was almost exactly the same speed as the naive loop. Then I tested it with `filteredKeys = (key for key in aDict.keys() if searchString in key)` and it was -- get this -- _four orders of magnitude faster_. Then I realized that's because the generator doesn't actually run :). Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to find keys that start with a prefix then you can use a binary search. Something like this will do the job:

```
import bisect
words = sorted("""
a b c stack stacey stackoverflow stacked star stare x y z
""".split())
n = len(words)
print n, "words"
print words
print
tests = sorted("""
r s ss st sta stack star stare stop su t
""".split())
for test in tests:
    i = bisect.bisect_left(words, test)
    if words[i] < test: i += 1
    print test, i
    while i < n and words[i].startswith(test):
        print i, words[i]
        i += 1
```

Output:

```
12 words
['a', 'b', 'c', 'stacey', 'stack', 'stacked', 'stackoverflow', 'star', 'stare',
'x', 'y', 'z']

r 3
s 3
3 stacey
4 stack
5 stacked
6 stackoverflow
7 star
8 stare
ss 3
st 3
3 stacey
4 stack
5 stacked
6 stackoverflow
7 star
8 stare
sta 3
3 stacey
4 stack
5 stacked
6 stackoverflow
7 star
8 stare
stack 4
4 stack
5 stacked
6 stackoverflow
star 7
7 star
8 stare
stare 8
8 stare
stop 9
su 9
t 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join all the keys into one long string with a suitable separator character and use the `find` method of the string. That is pretty fast.

Perhaps this code is helpful to you. The `search` method returns a list of dictionary values whose keys contain the substring `key`.

```
class DictLookupBySubstr(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary, separator='\n'):
        self.dic = dictionary
        self.sep = separator
        self.txt = separator.join(dictionary.keys())+separator

    def search(self, key):
        res = []
        i = self.txt.find(key)
        while i >= 0:
            left = self.txt.rfind(self.sep, 0, i) + 1
            right = self.txt.find(self.sep, i)
            dic_key = self.txt[left:right]
            res.append(self.dic[dic_key])
            i = self.txt.find(key, right+1)
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

dpath can solve this for you easily.

http://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

```
$ easy_install dpath
>>> for (path, value) in dpath.util.search(MY_DICT, "glob/to/start/{}".format(userinput), yielded=True):
>>> ...    # (do something with the path and value)
```

You can pass an eglob ('path/*/to/*/something/[0-9a-z]') for advanced searching.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using **has_key** solve this too.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html